# How can I figure out what files in AppData\Local\Temp I can delete safely?

Tags: windows-10, disk-space, disk-cleanup

My AppData\Local\Temp occupies 200GB, but cleanmgr.exe says

> Temporary Files: 1.16MB

[image]

Why is there the difference?

How can I figure out what files in the folder I can delete safely?

Comment: If you're looking at `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Temp`, *everything* can be deleted, unless you're in the middle of some operation. Look at the files, to be sure, but otherwise, delete ll to the *Recycle Bin*, if it fits (or if too much, delete permanently). You might need to reboot before the files can be deleted, if in use. A third-party tool such as *Wise Disk Cleaner*, https://www.wisecleaner.com/download.html, might help -- disk cleaning presets are fairly safe.

Comment: There are many temp file locations in Windows, clean manager only cleans up one location, which is different from the one you want to clean up.

Answer (score 0):

This Temp folder contains temporary files which can always be
deleted (unless they are in use).

It's a bit worrying that this folder has 200GB, but that Disk Cleanup
does not see this data.

I would suggest to start a Command Prompt (cmd) as Administrator
and run this command:

```
chkdsk C:
```

If any errors are found, take a backup of your disk
(since the following may have unpredictable effects),
then run :

```
chkdsk /f C:
```

After this is done, go into this Temp folder, select everything and delete.
Skip all files that cannot be deleted, since they would be in use by some
applications(s).

You may also use [CCleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/) to check
if more files can be cleaned out.

Some references for users that had the same problem as you
(with a similar solution) :

- [27 GB in AppData\Local\Temp](https://www.askwoody.com/forums/topic/27-gb-in-appdatalocaltemp/)
- [27 GB in admin\AppData\Local\Temp - Win10 21H2 Pro](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/27-gb-in-adminappdatalocaltemp-win10-21h2-pro/7373db3c-148a-4d26-bb0f-63113b9fce53)